# Unable to pass version header in ajax call. after using Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning

Tags: c#, jquery, api

I had created an webapi project in c# and used the version maintaining control provided by Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning.

I had enabled the version on the webapi controller.

firstly added this code into the webconfig file under register function.

```
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();
            config.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = false;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                o.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("version");
                o.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(o);
            });

            //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );           
        }
```

And also managed the version on the controller.

```
     [System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "version", methods: "*")]
     [ApiVersion("1.0")]
     public class AboutUsController : ApiController
     {
        /// <summary>
        /// it will get the AboutUs data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route(RoutePath.GetAboutUsData)]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAboutUsData()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage Result;
            try
            {
                var response = new AboutUs_BAL().GetAboutUs(CommonAction.Get);
                Result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, new 
                         JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return Result;
        }
     }
```

I had also managed the cors in the webconfig file in following manner.

```
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders> 
        <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />-->
        <add name="version" value="1.0" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,version" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
     </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I can call my API by using the controller or in C# code. I can easily pass the version as a header.
But as soon as I use the $. Jquery function to call an API it gives me an error.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://**.**.***.**/api/AboutUs/GetAboutUs',
            headers: { "version": "1.0" },
           // beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('version', '1.0'); },
            //headers: {
            //    "version": "1.0",
                
            //},
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                //alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
      It gives me an error of
```

1. ****Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://**.**.***.**/api/AboutUs/GetAboutUs' from origin
   'http://localhost:53234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
   pass
   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
   resource.****

   ```
   can anybody have maintained versioning in this manner and called an API in ajax?
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the answer after re-creating a demo project again with all the same package configuration. At this time I was having an extra piece of code in my old project when I compared that with my demo project.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```

But when i commented the above code then it works for me in my original project as well.
Now my Code looks like.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            //{
            //    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            //}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change url to api/v1/AboutUs/GetAboutUs

Comment: I am getting same error again. AboutUs:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.68.181.41/api/v1/AboutUs/GetAboutUs' from origin 'http://localhost:53234' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource..

Comment: How ever it works when I passes the version as a header in webrequest class from c# controller.  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_url);
                request.Headers.Add("version", "1.0");
It works fine. But when I used to call header from ajax it does not work.